# PayPal IPN | Drop Down Questions

Tags: php, session, post, paypal

On my PayPal IPN I had to change `$_POST['item_name']` to `$_POST['item_name1']` aswell as `$_POST['item_number']` to `$_POST['item_number1']` while testing in Sandbox IPN. I was wondering if I need to keep those or change them back when I go live.

Also I have a drop down list for the payment, I was wondering if the value of one of the list items is the item_name?

And one more question, can I access `$_SESSION` variables from my site in the IPN script? Or do I need to post them, and if so how do I post them?

Answer (score 0):

Generally the test IPN mirrors the live IPN. And the [IPN reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) says it's going to be `item_nameX` (where `X` is an incremented number). Assuming you're using Payments Standard, then `on0` will be `item_name1` and `os0` will be `item_number1`

You can't directly pass `$_SESSION` because PayPal will be POSTing data to you and would get a different session_id than your customer. You can use the `custom` field to pass the `session_id` and then use it in your IPN to set the `session_id`. This should be safe to do **after** you validate the IPN call.

```
session_id($_POST['custom']);
session_start();
```